# SSRS find out Data Source for a multiple reports

Tags: reporting-services, server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I've been tasked to find out the Data Source of 135 SSRS reports.

I want to avoid going into those reports individualy to find out what is the source of the reports.

Is there a way to run a query to find out the Data Source for the SSRS Report?

I've tried to run exsiting reports showing overview data about our SSRS web portal , but non of those inludes the data source for the reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the datasource names then you can use something like this. I've only picked a few columns for clarity ...

```
use ReportServer
select
    c.[Path]
    , c.Name 
    , dsrc.Name
    FROM [Catalog]c 
        JOIN DataSource dsrc on dsrc.ItemID = c.ItemID
```